# M matrix definition

Tags: linear-algebra

An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ that can be expressed in the form $A=sI-B$ where $B=(b_{ij})$ with $b_{ij}\geq 0$, $1\leq i,j\leq n$ and $s\geq \rho(B)$, where $\rho(B)$ is the maximum moduli of the eigenvalues of $B$, is called an M matrix. 
My doubt is: Can an M matrix be expressed in the above form in multiple ways or is there such a unique expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an M matrix can be expressed in multiple ways. In particular, if $\lambda \ge 0$, then we can write
$$A = (s + \lambda)I - (B + \lambda I). \tag{$\star$}$$
Note that, since the entries of $B$ and $\lambda I$ are non-negative, so too are the entries of $B + \lambda I$. Further, $B + \lambda I$ simply increases each eigenvalue of $B$ by $\lambda$, and so the maximum moduli of $B$ can increase by at most $\lambda$. So, we see that
$$\rho(B + \lambda I) \le \rho(B) + \lambda \le s + \lambda.$$
That is, $(\star)$ is a sum of matrices in the given form, no matter the value of $\lambda \ge 0$, and so the sum is far from unique.